# Save userform controls layour after user creates it on button click event

Tags: vba, user-controls

I have setup a dynamic userform in Excel VBA which allows the user to choose how many rows they want in a combination of comboboxes and textboxes. Once the user creates there form, I want to be able to process calculations as they choose items from drop down lists and enter numerical values.

I am able to create the form without issue but can not seem to work with the created controls as they do not appear to be saved in memory in which I can access them.

My control creation loop predefines the names sequentially however my change code doesn't seem to reference them as they normally do when saved as part of the starting userform.

I've been trying to export the created form after it has been created but that does not seem to work and is not really a viable option as multiple users will be using their own instance of the forms.

Here is the code of what successfully creates the list along with the correct properties and source data.

```
'Create new door list based on user number input
Private Sub btnds1dl1CreatDoorList_Click()

Dim i As Long, x As Integer, number As Long
Dim txtB1, cmbB1 As Control

number = InputBox("Enter # or door list rows to create", "Enter number between 1 and 100")
number = number + 1

With UForm
    For i = 2 To number

        'Add each row from left to right starting at control 1 and ending at 11.

        '<<=========================  ADD 2 COMBO BOXES
        'ADD CABINET
        Set cmbB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "cmdboxs1dlcab" & i)
        With cmbB1
            '.Name = "cmdboxs1dlcab" & i
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 72
            .Left = 18
            .Top = 24 * (i - 1) + 228
            .RowSource = "CABINET_TYPE"
            .Value = "Select"
            .BackStyle = 0
        End With

        'ADD SINGLE OR PAIR
        Set cmbB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "cmdboxs1dlsp" & i)
        With cmbB1
            '.Name = "cmdboxs1dlsp" & i
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 72
            .Left = 96
            .Top = 24 * (i - 1) + 228
             .RowSource = "SINGLE_PAIR"
            .Value = "Select"
            .BackStyle = 0
        End With


        '<<=========================  ADD 9 TEXT BOXES
        'ADD QTY OPENINGS
        Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtB1
            .Name = "txtboxds1dl1qo" & i
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 43
            .Left = 186
            .Top = 24 * (i - 1) + 228
        End With

        'ADD OPENING WIDTH
        Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtB1
            .Name = "txtboxds1dl1ow" & i
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 43
            .Left = 246
            .Top = 24 * (i - 1) + 228
        End With

        'ADD OPENING HEIGHT
        Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtB1
            .Name = "txtboxds1dl1oh" & i
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 43
            .Left = 306
            .Top = 24 * (i - 1) + 228
        End With

        'ADD FINISH NET WIDTH
        Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtB1
            .Name = "txtboxds1dl1fnw" & i
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 43
            .Left = 378
            .Top = 24 * (i - 1) + 228
        End With

        'ADD FINISH NET HEIGHT
        Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtB1
            .Name = "txtboxds1dl1fnh" & i
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 43
            .Left = 444
            .Top = 24 * (i - 1) + 228
        End With

        'ADD QUANTITY
        Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtB1
            .Name = "txtboxds1dl1q" & i
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 43
            .Left = 522
            .Top = 24 * (i - 1) + 228
        End With

        'ADD WIDTH
        Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtB1
            .Name = "txtboxds1dl1w" & i
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 43
            .Left = 575
            .Top = 24 * (i - 1) + 228
        End With

        'ADD HEIGHT
        Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtB1
            .Name = "txtboxds1dl1h" & i
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 43
            .Left = 627
            .Top = 24 * (i - 1) + 228
        End With

         'ADD AREA (SQ FT.)
        Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtB1
            .Name = "txtboxds1dl1a" & i
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 43
            .Left = 678
            .Top = 24 * (i - 1) + 228
        End With

        Call AdjustScrollBar ' Adjust scroll bar to account for new rows

    Next i

    Call AdjustFormHeight ' Adjust form height to account for new rows

End With


End Sub
```

The result I am hoping for is after this code is triggered, the form is saved to memory and used as if the form started that way. I want to be able to make various changes automatically based on the users input and have the full ability to monitor and refence any controls changed.

Thanks for your help

Comment: "the form is saved to memory"  - for how long is the form to be saved?  Really the only thing you need to recall is how many rows to create, and your form can rebuild itself each time it's loaded.  If you want to preserve the already-built layout ten you can hide it instead of unloading it.  Note you have `With Uform` wrapping your main code, but you don't ever use that context.  Also, if this code is in the userform itself, you can use `Me` in place of the form name.

Comment: ...and if you want the newly-added controls to trigger events then you will need to use a Control array: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Tim, I had left with the With in the code by mistake. I’m taking a slightly different approach and copying the entered values to sheets that won’t be seen by the user. So far it seems to be working but need to test on the created controls. I’ll test that and comment back in a few.

Comment: Ok, tested and even though the controls have the same name every time they are created, the code is not able to detect the change. I’ll try the array approach and hopefully that works. New to coding to monitor a users input as it occurs.

Comment: It looks like the array approach may work. Can you provide me an example of how I could detect any control changes and copy the resulting value to a worksheet cell range. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example which just links controls to worksheet cells: in this form it could arguably be more-easily handled by setting `ControlSource` (https://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA2/excelvba2lesson15.htm) but if you want it to be more flexible (ie. be able to validate inputs) then you will need to handle events and do it this way.

Code for event-handling class "clsControl":

```
Option Explicit

Public linkedCell As Range
Public WithEvents cbo As MSForms.ComboBox
Public WithEvents txt As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub cbo_Change()
    'here you handle the change in a combo box
    Me.linkedCell.Value = cbo.Value
End Sub

Private Sub txt_Change()
    'here you handle the change in a text box
    Me.linkedCell.Value = txt.Value
End Sub
```

Code in the userform:

```
Option Explicit

Private ControlsCollection As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim n As Long, t As Long, rngCombo As Range, rngTxt As Range
    Dim con As Object

    Set ControlsCollection = New Collection

    t = 20 'top position
    'start positions for linked cells
    Set rngCombo = Sheet2.Range("A2")
    Set rngTxt = Sheet2.Range("C2")

    For n = 1 To 10

        Set con = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "cmbo_" & n)
        With con
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 72
            .Left = 18
            .top = t + (n - 1) * 25
            .RowSource = "Some_List"
        End With
        ControlsCollection.Add ControlWrapper(con, rngCombo.Offset(n - 1, 0))

        Set con = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txt_" & n)
        With con
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 72
            .Left = 100
            .top = t + (n - 1) * 25
        End With
        ControlsCollection.Add ControlWrapper(con, rngTxt.Offset(n - 1, 0))

    Next n

End Sub

'Create an instance of our event-handling class, and assign a control
'   and a linked cell
Private Function ControlWrapper(con As Object, rng As Range) As clsControl
    Dim rv As New clsControl
    'assign to the appropriate control type in the calss instance
    Select Case TypeName(con)
        Case "ComboBox": Set rv.cbo = con
        Case "TextBox": Set rv.txt = con
    End Select
    Set rv.linkedCell = rng
    Set ControlWrapper = rv
End Function
```

The resulting forn and the linked cells, after filling in a few values:

[image]

**EDIT 6/4/2019**

Here's something a little different - each instance of the class represents a row on the userform.  I've removed any linked cell references to keep the code brief.

The class module:

```
Option Explicit

'each item is a control on a "row" of the userform
'here we just havce two combos and a textbox
'   but could be more...
Public WithEvents cbo1 As MSForms.ComboBox
Public WithEvents cbo2 As MSForms.ComboBox
Public WithEvents txt As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub cbo1_Change()
    'handle the change in a combo box
    Me.txt.Value = cbo1.Value & ":" & cbo2.Value
End Sub

Private Sub cbo2_Change()
    'handle the change in a combo box
    Me.txt.Value = cbo1.Value & ":" & cbo2.Value
End Sub

Private Sub txt_Change()
    'here you handle the change in a text box
End Sub
```

The userform code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim n As Long, t As Long
    Dim con As Object, obj As clsControl

    Set ControlsCollection = New Collection

    t = 20 'top position

    For n = 1 To 10

        Set obj = New clsControl

        Set con = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "cmbo_" & n)
        With con
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 72
            .Left = 18
            .Top = t + (n - 1) * 25
            .RowSource = "Some_List"
        End With
        Set obj.cbo1 = con

        Set con = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "cmbo_" & n)
        With con
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 72
            .Left = 100
            .Top = t + (n - 1) * 25
            .RowSource = "Some_List"
        End With
        Set obj.cbo2 = con

        Set con = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txt_" & n)
        With con
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 72
            .Left = 200
            .Top = t + (n - 1) * 25
        End With
        Set obj.txt = con

        ControlsCollection.Add obj

    Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried the code on a new userform and getting the following error. Any ideas what may be causing this? Thanks

Comment: Compile Error - user defined type not defined

Comment: You may need to make some adjustments - eg  to `Sheet2` if you don't have a sheet with codename Sheet2.  Also you need to add a new class named "clsControl" and paste in the code from above.

Comment: Compiler is highlighting

Private Function ControlWrapper(con As Object, rng As Range) As clsControl

Comment: You did not add the class for the event handling, or you did not name it "clsControl"

Comment: My sheet2 was actually sheet14. Made that change and still getting the compile error???

Comment: It may be the class name. My class is named Class 1. I'll test that change now. Thanks

Comment: That was the issue. Everything works now. Just need to modify it for my specific needs. Thanks again. I have been working on this forever!!! Greatly appreciate it :-)

Comment: I’m able to get everything to work except one calculation piece. I need to set a text box value based on what was selected from the 2 combo box lists. How can I make this part work? Thanks

Comment: One possibility is to add both the combobox and the textbox to the same instance of clsControl - then you can directly access the textbox from the combo change event

Comment: Hi, I’ve been trying to make your suggestion work and while I am getting the correct result for one of the drop down, I’m not able to push my calculation to the adjacent text box. Can you provide some sample code so I can see what I’m missing. Thanks so much

Comment: See my edit above: instead of one class instance per control, you can make one per row, and all the controls in that row can interact.